# ssh2_scp_send(): supplied resource is not a valid SSH2 Session resource

Tags: php, ssh2-sftp

I try to create directories and upload recursively files from some local folders in two `foreach` loop.

All seem to be ok `ssh2_connect()` and `ssh2_auth_password()` return true.

Also folders creation are ok. Folders are created in remote.

But after that when I try to upload the files from that folders to remote I got this error:

```
ssh2_scp_send(): supplied resource is not a valid SSH2 Session resource
```

Here are my example:

```
<?php
    $sshRes = ssh2_connect('my_hostname.com', 22);
    //both return true here
    ssh2_auth_password($sshRes, $user_ssh, $pass_ssh);

    $sftp = ssh2_sftp($sshRes);

    $local_folders = glob($my_local_path."/*",GLOB_ONLYDIR);

    $remote_base = "/remote_base";

    foreach($local_folders as $local_folder){

        $folder_name = basename($local_folder);

        $remote_path = $remote_base."/".$folder_name;

        if(!is_dir("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/$remote_path")){

            if(ssh2_sftp_mkdir($sftp, $remote_path, 0755)){
                echo "$remote_path created ok"
            }else{
                echo "$remote_path creation failed";
            }

        }   

        $files = glob($local_folder."/*");

        foreach($files as $local_file){

            $file_name = basename($local_file);

            //!!! here I got the error.!!!
            if(ssh2_scp_send($sftp, $local_file, $remote_path."/".$file_name, 0644)){               
                    echo "$file_name UPLOAD OK";
                }else{
                    echo "$file_name UPLOAD FAIL";          
                }           

        }

    }
?>
```

Someone can tell me what is wrong ?

Comment: `scp` is not the same as `sftp`, are you sure you shouldn't be sending `$sshRes` instead of `$sftp`?

Comment: Just checked [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php), the first parameter for `ssh2_scp_send()` should be `An SSH connection link identifier, obtained from a call to ssh2_connect().` -- so yes, you should use `$sshRes` instead of `$sftp`.

Comment: Bfffff .... will be try now.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Thank You ... that work ... I'm feel ridiculous  :)